# When I set jquery autocomplete minLength to 0 it keeps running after the user chose an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu, autocomplete

I am using Jquery autocomplete with ajax.
Everything works fine except when I set minLength to 0.
When I choose an element from the list, the autocomplete doesn't stop running and shows me the list again.

Here is the code:

```
 $("#id_from").autocomplete({
     source: function (request, response) {
         $.ajax({
             url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/core/get_from_cities",
                 dataType: "json",
                 data: {term: request.term},
                 success: function (data) {
                     response($.map(data.data, function (item) {
                         return {
                             label: item.value,
                             value: item.value
                         }
                     }));
                 }
             });
         },
         minLength: 0         
     });
```

Thanks..

EDIT:
Here is the solution I came up with:

```
 $("#id_to").focus(function() {
                $( "#id_to" ).autocomplete( "enable" );
            });


            $("#id_ffrom").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/core/get_from_cities",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {term: request.term},
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.data, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.city,
                                    value: item.city,

                                }
                            }));
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength: 0,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $('#id_from_country').val(ui.item.country)
                    $("#id_ffrom").autocomplete( "disable" );

                }

            });
```

Comment: You're missing a `"` at the end of your url.

Comment: url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/core/get_from_cities"

Comment: why are you setting minLength to zero?

Comment: The url is not the issue. but thanks. I want to set minLength to 0 so the options will appear when the user click on the field.

Comment: How about adding `select: function(event, ui) { $(this).autocomplete("close"); });`

Comment: Thanks Matt but it didn't help.